# Oracle Unifier - System Reports Rest API not exist or not enabled

Tags: oracle, primavera

How to pull out the Sytem Reports by APIs use not the UDR Reports "This one has API that we can use" from Oracle Primavera Unifier System?

Syetem Reports --> Can't find any API
UDR I can pull the reports.

Can't find any API that helps to Pull out the System Reports

If no Rest APIs to pull out the System reports, is there a way around?